# float to char array in C, sprintf

Tags: c, char, printf

I've been googling but I haven't found a simple float to char using the sprintf function. So far - this is all I've written in my small code section. The problem is that I always get a 0 return.

```
   int main()
   {
        float num_input[9];
        printf("Enter a real number: ");
        scanf("%f", &num_input);
        printf("%f", num_input);
        char str_num[9];
        sprintf(str_num, "%f", &num_input);
        printf(str_num);

        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you to everyone that helped! I finally saw what I did wrong and learnt more. The final code written was:

```
float num_input[9];
printf("Enter a real number: ");
scanf("%f", &num_input);
char str_num[9];
int index = 0;
sprintf(str_num, "%f", num_input[index]);
```

Comment: `float num_input[9];`--> `float num_input;` and `printf(str_num);` --> `puts(str_num);`

Comment: Look at your compiler warnings and fix those before even considering requesting for help. Or ask about the warnings if you do not understand them. That will save everyone alot of time.

Comment: In addition to @SouravGhosh comments: `sprintf(str_num, "%f", &num_input);` --> `sprintf(str_num, "%f", num_input);`

Comment: @kaylum I don't have any compiler warnings. That's the problem. When I go to print out the %c I just get a 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf(str_num, "%f", &num_input);` is wrong. You should use something like:

```
sprintf(str_num, "%f", num_input[index]);  /* 0 <= index < 9 */
/*                    ^          ^^^^^  */
```

After this keep the fingers crossed that `str_num` doesn't overflow.

Remember that `"%f"` specifier of `printf` family of function should have a matching `double` or `float` (`float` becomes `double` after default argument promotion).

---

Perhaps you should make the similar fix for `scanf` and `printf` also:

```
scanf("%f", &num_input[0]);
printf("%f", num_input[0]);
```

Comment: Why do you need `float num_input[9]` in the first place. The whole program will work with a single `float num_input` and OP is not using the other 8 floats in the array.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I am using it actually but I didn't include that part of my code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I finally got the code sorted!

 `float num_input[9];
 printf("Enter a real number: ");
 scanf("%f", &num_input);
 char str_num[9];
 int index = 0;
 sprintf(str_num, "%f", num_input[index]);`

Comment: `scanf` should be changed to `scanf("%f", &num_input[index]);`